# I need to know when should i use wp_redirect()?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am using `wp_redirect()` to redirect to a URL but it gives me the warning below and does not redirect. When should I use `wp_redirect()`? And does any one know how `wp_redirect()` works?

```
**[Fri Feb 28 03:58:36 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:
  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
  started at /home/virgo/public_html/others/sites/wepay/wp-content/
  themes/twentythirteen/header.php:43) in /home/virgo/public_html/o
  thers/sites/wepay/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 875, referer: 
  http://127.0.0.1/others/sites/wepay/?page_id=15**
```

Comment: You can't use it after anything has been output, since it sends a redirect by using a `Location` header, and the headers come before the body of an HTTP message.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7381661/2126792 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/12770075/2126792.

Answer (score 1):

Headers need to come first therefore you have to place this before any output. This includes error messages. If you run some code that has an issue which generates a notice this will prevent the redirect from running.

Take a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

get_header is the latest point.

I'd suggest doing it once WP has been setup so you can use all conditionals including use of `$post` but still early. The most appropriate hook in my opinion would be 'wp'.

```
function wpse_redirect() {
    if ( ENTER A CONDITIONAL ) {
        wp_redirect( 'redirect-location' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_redirect' );
```