# Internal Server Error When i upload a WordPress Files To Online Server

Tags: php, wordpress

I coded a WordPress theme and then i uploaded the whole WordPress directory to my online site server , The home page is working fine but when i jump into the single content page or i try to login it gives me the below error , please help me out!

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@iamifti.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Look in the error log.

Comment: I am getting this error Sir "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lsbeqtit/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/lsbeqtit/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1173"

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59763/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images

Comment: Thanks Sir I checked the erorr logs it works for me , it was just spacing Problem . I removed the spaces from my WPCONFIG file and that's it !

Comment: Good practice is to remove the ?> from the end of a PHP script as this usually causes the issue.

Comment: Yes John Reid , you are 100% right buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to make some changes on your `functions.php` file which plays an important role in your theme functioning.

If this isn't solved your problem there many be any syntax errors or spacing errors in your code in the theme file.

For allowing the redirecting you should use

```
add_action('init', 'do_output_buffer');
```

The function `do_output_buffer` would be

```
function do_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
}
```

Please have a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381661/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-wordpress-issue)