# Missing argument and modify header information error

Tags: php

If anyone can help me I would be thankful.
I am getting this error.

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 1 for DonationSession::GetPaymentURL(), called in /home/desolutionrp/public_html/web/payment.php on line 18 and defined in <b>/public_html/web/inc/donate.class.php</b> on line <b>95</b><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/desolutionrp/public_html/web/inc/donate.class.php:95) in <b>/public_html/web/payment.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
```

I checked out what's on those lines and for the first error this is the line:

```
function GetPaymentURL($email) {
   return "https://www." . (config_Sandbox ? "sandbox." : "") . "paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?on0=donationid&os0=" .$this->index . "&on1=steamid&os1=" . $this->steamid . "&cmd=_xclick&business=" . config_PayPalEmail . "&no_shipping=1&currency_code=USD&lc=EN&item_name=" . config_ProductName . "&amount=" . $this->value;
}
```

And for the second error the line says:

```
header("Location:" . $donation->GetPaymentURL());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `GetPaymentURL` requires you to pass an argument in for `$email`

You can handle this in 3 ways:

1) Give a default value to `$email`

```
function GetPaymentURL($email = '') {
    // return your data
}
```

2) remove the $email param since it doesn't seem to be used

```
function GetPaymentURL() {
    // return your data
}
```

3) Provide the data in the function call

```
header("Location:" . $donation->GetPaymentURL('emaiAddress@emailDomain.com'));
```

Your second issue is likely caused by your script printing out data to the screen and can be handled by using output buffering:

[Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... Wordpress Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381661/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-wordpress-issue)

More info on this error:

[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The `GetPaymentUrl()` function expects one parameter - `$email`.  Make sure that you're passing an email address when you call that function.  The second error - "cannot modify header information" - is because the first error message has been printed to the screen.  Once the first error is fixed, the second will disappear.