# WordPress - Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, wordpress

I have copied a functional WordPress website from a server to another. I didn't do any changes to the files, I've only copied and installed it to another server.

Here is the error I get:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truhealthmedical/public_html/articles/wp-config.php:1) in /home/truhealthmedical/public_html/articles/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3588

Also I got a similar error, but to this one, when I try to access /wp-admin:

> /home/truhealthmedical/public_html/articles/wp-includes/functions.php

I checked and there are no spaces or "?>" tags to wp-config.php. My perplexity is that I don't understand why it's working on a server, and on the other one it's not.

I have read a lot of articles, and tried a lot of possibilities, but still not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381661/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-wordpress-issue

Answer (score 0):

I have often got these type of warning and this worked for me: You can put ob_start(); function in the top of your wp-config.php file. This might work for you too.